# Adding together cube measures with different where clauses

Tags: mdx, olap, cube

I Have two MDX queries,

`select 
[Measures].[Goals A] on 0
from [FDC Star]
where [Squad A].[Squad Key]`

And

`select 
[Measures].[Goals B] on 0
from [FDC Star]
where [Squad B].[Squad Key]`

I would like to add the two values together but being very new to MDX I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use calculated members:

```
WITH
   MEMBER [Measures].[A] AS ([Measures].[Goals A], [Squad A].[Squad Key])
   MEMBER [Measures].[B] AS ([Measures].[Goals B], [Squad B].[Squad Key])
SELECT {[Measures].[A], [Measures].[B]} ON 0
FROM [FDC Star]
```